# Greping in python

Tags: python

I'm using linux server and storing there files where are some information about device status like:

```
TE 20170105 082502000244;DEV My_device;Q Device_IP;HOST lover_case_device_name;L watch;S A+r;SYS uptime;TO 20170105 082502;PRIO 1;VAL 13793460;CNT 0;TR 0,1,300,1,1800,5,0,20;TXT Linux:  00:25:02 up 159 days, 15:31,  0 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.07, 0.01;
```

I would like to retrieve information marked with flag Dev (My_device) and uptime (only days) associated to this device . Uptime has line "TXT Linux:  00:25:02 up 159 days"

I've tried the following:

```
import re
azf = open('/data/2017/01/05/09.azf')
for line in azf:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.findall('[CFR]{3}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{5}|[days]{3,}', line) :
        print line
```

The regex pattern is matching exactly what I want, but it's just spitting all information from file.

Comment: On SO we usually try to help with problems in your code. This of cause requires some code. So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
if re.findall('[CFR]{3}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{5}|[days]{3,}', line) :
    print line
```

Part of your problem is that you're printing the whole line.  If it's not what you want, then don't print it. :-)  Also, you mostly likely want to use a raw strings with your regular expressions since they often contain backslashes.

If you did this instead:

```
for match in re.findall('[CFR]{3}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{5}|[days]{3,}', line):
    print match
```

You'd see what you're matching, and you'd discover that it's only "days".

I think you want something more like this:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint


def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        entries = {}
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            # The regex here attempts to match each entry which
            # starts off with a sequence of letters and is terminated
            # with a semicolon.
            for match in re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]* [^;]*', line):
                key, value = match.split(' ', 1)
                entries[key] = value
        return entries


def parse_days(text):
    if text:
        # To parse the number of days, we group around where
        # days is expected to be...
        match = re.search(r'up (\d+) days', entries['TXT'])
        if match:
            # ...and pull the value out if there is a match
            return match.group(1)

    return None


entries = read_data('data.azf')

# Print the entries
pprint(entries)

# Show the ones we're interested in
print entries['DEV']
print entries['TXT']

if 'TXT' in entries:
    # Parse the days
    print parse_days(entries['TXT'])
```

`read_data()` would read the file and parse the contents into entries, since they seem to be well structured, and return them as a dictionary.  I'm not sure if more than one line can be expected, but I chose to go with the latest match wins.

`parse_days()` would get passed the `TXT` entry, and it will pull out the number of days, if it's in there, or return `None`.

Here's the output given your example data:

```
{'CNT': '0',
 'DEV': 'My_device',
 'HOST': 'lover_case_device_name',
 'L': 'watch',
 'PRIO': '1',
 'Q': 'Device_IP',
 'S': 'A+r',
 'SYS': 'uptime',
 'TE': '20170105 082502000244',
 'TO': '20170105 082502',
 'TR': '0,1,300,1,1800,5,0,20',
 'TXT': 'Linux:  00:25:02 up 159 days, 15:31,  0 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.07, 0.01',
 'VAL': '13793460'}
My_device
Linux:  00:25:02 up 159 days, 15:31,  0 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.07, 0.01
159
```

Comment: Thank you jszakmeister for the help. I will check tomorrow at work how to apply this.

Answer (score 0):

Well after few tests I've got what I want to...
Just for someone who is not a python programmer like me:)

```
    import re

f = open('/data/2017/01/09/08.azf')


strToSearch = ""

for line in f:
   strToSearch += line

patFinder1 = re.compile('(?=([XXX]{3}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{5}))+.*(\s\w[up]\s\d{1,3})')

findPat1 = re.findall(patFinder1, strToSearch)

for i in findPat1:
   print(i)
```

XXX -my device name has always 3 the same letters and there is only last letter which is changing.

The result is:
('XXXN02142', ' up 5')

My next step would be to format this print and write to csv file.